# Folder browser: Copy to restricted locations?

Tags: root, folder

Can I launch the folder browser as root so I can copy files to restricted locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do exactly as you want, `gksudo nautilus` will work.

This prompts a follow-up question - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Copy an msi file from a USB drive to `/usr/share/wine`. But aside from that, I often find myself needing to go to the command line for things I just feel like doing with a GUI. Especially, simple things like this.

Comment: @George Bailey: that's cuz Linux strictly devides things into admin and user things ;)

Comment: @George Bailey: Just take extra care what you do when running Nautilus as root. You will then also have the power to seriously damage your system.